# Node.js + mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In some tutorials I seen these two instructions:

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').mongoClient;
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

The first one look like as a property, the second one look like as a constructor.
The `typeof` operator return `'undefined'` in the first occurrence, `'function'` in the second one.

Can someone explain me why?

Thank you!

Comment: Because javascript is case sensitive? If `.mongoClient` is undefined it is literally because it's undefined. If `.MongoClient` shows a function, then it is a function and should be called via `.MongoClient()`. The capitalisation of these things does not play a part whether it is a property or a constructor; that is naught but a matter of convention

Comment: Maybe those first tutorials just have a typo? ) Because it's `MongoClient` (it's used to create instances of clients where URL are passed as parameter), and yes, JS is case-sensitive.

Comment: From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "*Write a title that summarizes the specific problem*" Just *"Node.js + mongo*" is not searchable to future readers

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the [mongodb github](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/index.js), the module only exports `MongoClient`.

Maybe in some previous version, it exported a `mongoClient` instead and that's why tutorials differ

Answer (score 0):

Only `const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;` is a valid way to extract mongoClient from mongodb library.

Not sure where `const mongoClient = require('mongodb').mongoClient;` is used and i wonder if it works. It might be used in old versions.

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html